# What is the use of cut in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Whats the difference between these two in terms of trace of steps?

1)

```
find(X,[X|Tail]).
find(X,[Head|Tail]):-find(X,Tail).
```

2)

```
find(X,[X|Tail]):-!.
find(X,[Head|Tail]):-find(X,Tail).
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [cut processing in prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769536/cut-processing-in-prolog)

Comment: its a bit different as according to me , output is not changing in this case due to !.

Comment: The output will change depending upon what your query is. Try `find(b, [a,b,c,b,d])` with each case and see what happens. The first one will find two solutions. The second will cut after it finds a solution and offers no backtracking. So any subsequent solutions are not found. This is particularly noticeable if you wrote these predicates to output, say, a count of occurrences.

Answer (score 4):

When Prolog executes a query, it seeks to find all solutions that make the query successful (true). In a very simple case, if I have:

```
foo(a).
foo(b).
```

And I enter:

```
| ?- foo(X).

X = a ? ;

X = b

yes
```

You can see that Prolog finds two solutions and then stops. What happens here is that after Prolog finds the solution `X = a` and you press `;`, you ask Prolog to find more solutions. Prolog then backtracks to the most recently encountered "choice point" (the point in the query execution where it had a decision to make regarding what to choose a valid alternative selection) and tries another selection. In this case, it finds `foo(b)` and matches `foo(X)`, so you also get `X = b`. Prolog has no more choice points after finding `X = b`, so it offers no choice after prompting for `X = b` and just says `yes` (it succeeded on the last go).

The Prolog cut (`!`) is used to eliminate a choice point. Or stated another way, it's telling Prolog, *don't backtrack prior to this point*.

Let's now introduce a cut into our simple case:

```
foo(a) :- !.
foo(b).
```

And the query then becomes:

```
| ?- foo(X).

X = a

yes
```

The cut has eliminated backtracking after Prolog finds the solution `X = a`.

In the given example with `find/2`, if we perform the query, `find(b, [a,b,c]).` with the non-cut version, we get:

```
| ?- find(b, [a,b,c]).

true ? ;

no
```

If we do the same with the cut version, we get:

```
| ?- find(b, [a,b,c]).

yes
```

Hmm. They both successfully find `b` but the results look a little different. In the first case, Prolog finds `b` in `[a,b,c]` when it finally encounters the clause, `find(X, [X|_]).` But there's no cut, so there's a choice point here since there's still the following clause, `find(X, [_|Tail) :-...`. Prolog says, `true ?` and asks if you want to backtrack to find more solutions (go back to the choice point). Since it can't find another solution from that choice point, it finally says, "no".

In the second case, Prolog finds the first solution (success) via the clause `find(X, [X|_]) :- !.` but the cut eliminates the choice point and tells Prolog, *if you get here, don't bother allowing backtracking to any more solutions from this point*. So you just get "yes" for success and Prolog stops looking for more solutions.

When there's only one solution anyway, the cut just removes unnecessary backtracking to find more solutions that aren't there. But if there is more than one solution available, the cut will prevent Prolog from backtracking and finding some of those solutions.

Here's another trivial example that illustrates the "pruning of solutions" the cut can do:

```
a(1). a(2).
b(1). b(2).

foo(X, Y) :- a(X), b(Y).
```

Then the query:

```
| ?- foo(X, Y).

X = 1
Y = 1 ? a

X = 1
Y = 2

X = 2
Y = 1

X = 2
Y = 2

yes
| ?-
```

Introducing a cut:

```
foo(X, Y) :- a(X), !, b(Y).
```

Then the query:

```
| ?- foo(X, Y).

X = 1
Y = 1 ? a

X = 1
Y = 2

yes
| ?-
```

What's happening in this case is the cut is preventing backtracking to find the additional options for `a(X)` in the clause. But there's still a choice point when finding solutions for `b(Y)`, and we didn't cut those. If we had put the cut after `b(Y)` as follows, then those would be cut as well:

```
foo(X, Y) :- a(X), b(Y), !.
```

Then it would only find one solution:

```
| ?- foo(X, Y).

X = 1
Y = 1

yes
| ?-
```

Many Prolog books have some discussion of cut. A good one is, *Programming in Prolog* by Clocksin & Mellish. It has diagrams, etc, showing how the cut and choice points work.